# having trouble with a mod_rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

want to rewrite urls like `site.com/software` to `wp-content/themes/dir/software.php` and something is not working..  Here's what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^software wp-content/themes/dir/software.php [L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite rules are processed in the order that they are encountered.  In this case, every request is getting pushed to `index.php` before your `software` rule is encountered (assuming that `software` doesn't exist in the system as a directory or file).  The `[L]` on the end of the first rule tells Apache to stop reading rules, so it doesn't even bother processing the next one.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^software wp-content/themes/dir/software.php [L]        
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks, that worked!  one thing I don't understand is I did try changing the order of index and software, but I didn't go higher than Rewrite conditions.. What's the significance there?  THANKS!

Comment: `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the very next `RewriteRule` that gets encountered.  If you had moved the "software" `RewriteRule` above the "index.php" rule, then the `RewriteCond` lines would have then applied only to the "software" rule, which isn't what you would have wanted.

The reverse of that is that anything you put *under* the "index.php" rule won't be affected by the `RewriteCond` directives above the "index.php" rule.

Comment: another question if you be so kind..
I'm setting up the google adwords and it's not meshing well with the mod_rewrite (getting the Invalid HTTP Response Code from adwords)

The rule I use is 
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ wp-content/themes/dir/$1.php [L]

.. I read that Google is adding an id to the end of the request.. could that be the problem?